# I am unsure about a specific question. I do not know which SO site is suitable for this.

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On which site am I supposed to ask about where to post a specific question. I hope this one doesn't get closed.

I wanted to ask the following but dunno where I should:

"What are some good examples of CRM emails sent by different companies to their existing and potential customers? Those aware of Zoho CRM, SalesForce, MS Dynamic CRM can answer better I guess. Please help. Thanks."

Comment: This is the correct site to ask for site recommendations. That's why we have the tag. :) And thanks for asking.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a good question for any Stack Exchange site.

It falls under the open-ended and chatty end of the spectrum - it invites discussion and multiple answers that are mostly backed by opinion and not fact.

At both Stack Overflow and Programmers, there is a specific rule about off-site recommendation questions (whether for books, tutorials, libraries and such) - they are not allowed.

Perhaps a site like http://slant.co would be a better place for you to ask something like this.